# About Menu in my Xcode 4 Project remains disabled

Tags: xcode, macos, disabled-control, about-box

Unfortunately the About Menu of my project is disabled and I can´t enable it.

I set up an IBOUTLET

```
IBOutlet NSMenuItem *aboutMenu;
```

and then I tried to enable it like this in applicationDidFinishLaunching, although I think it should not be disabled until I say so:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification   {
   [aboutMenu setEnabled:TRUE];
}
```

Anyway, it´s still disabled.

Any idea what could be wrong?

I have this problem only in one project. In my other projects it´s always automatically enabled.

Comment: Did you wire up the `IBOutlet` with the `NSMenuItem` in Storyboard / XIB ?

Comment: Do you have -any- code disabling the elements ?

Comment: No code is disabling the menus and I have correctly wire up.

Comment: Well, I found that the Main Menu was not connected to the Main Window as a menu. Doing this activated the menu. Still mysterious. I definitely didn´t remove the connection.

Comment: Please add that as an answer and accept it so that people don't spend time on a problem that's already solved.